# Get browser for logging in Watir?

Tags: ruby, watir

I want to show which browser is being used in a series of tests, i.e., whether the browser is Chrome or Firefox.

I have:

```
def initialize(browser)
  @browser = browser
  $log.info("\n"+"#{browser}"+" Browser initialized") 
end
```

It returns Watir:

```
<Watir::Browser:0x24553a5d286c4da2 url="https://url" title="page name">
```

Are there any ideas how to get it to return the browser name instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it by directly accessing the underlying selenium-webdriver functionality:

```
browser.driver.capabilities[:browser_name]
#=> 'chrome'
```

Easier solution is to do (from http://watirwebdriver.com/determining-which-browser/):

```
browser.driver.browser
#=> :chrome
```

Answer (score 5):

There is also method in Watir API, which also works in watir-classic:

```
browser.name # => chrome
```